# MVC 5 deleting a row that has a foreign key on it

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a table A that is referenced by a foreign key constraint from table B. Is there a way to delete a row from table A?

Comment: What are you using for data access? Entity Framework?

Comment: ASP.NET MVC has nothing to do with databases. Are you using Entity Framework? If so, what version? DB-First or Code-First?

Comment: @Escobar5 yea EF

Comment: @Dai yes entity framework, version 6 db first

Comment: You need to configure cascade delete for the table, check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23667430/641345

Comment: most likely you mucked up your classes in code first then and disabled the cascade delete. Can you show your class with the foreign key?

Comment: @Travis Well I have a class product and a class sales... sales(ProductID) points to Products(ID)

Comment: Show your sales class so we can see the decoration you have for it. BUT you probably REALLY do not want to do cascading deletes with those table names.

Comment: @Escobar5 what do I have to change "JohnsChildTable" with? The table that points to the other table or..?

Comment: @TravisActon I'm using the auto generated from emdx, nothing special

Comment: Apologies, I swore I read you were using code first and not DB. So before you go ANY further. Would you really want a cascade delete with those table names. If you delete a product then it would delete a sale record. Probably would be best to put an active flag on your product table and just flip the product to inactive if you ever wanted to disable it for customers. This would leave all your records intact. Sorry as I know this is not the answer to your question.

Comment: @TravisActon let's say that i want to delete it... what should I do

Comment: Then your modification should really be on the SQL end of things so that everything that touches the table would follow the same business rules even if it were outside your application: Reference this answer for the sql transaction:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260688/how-do-i-use-cascade-delete-with-sql-server

Comment: @TravisActon can't i do it with c# code?

Comment: I'm not of aware of any automated way to do it in EF other than deleting the children pre parent deletion in code itself. Would be interesting if anyone else has had success using conditional mapping or something.

Answer (score 1):

A way would be to enable cascade delete. Go to SQL Server Management Studio and where you defined the FK set the delete rule to cascade.
It is the easiest way but not always the best.

[image]